# How to remove Dataframe from list if in exclusion list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame

This has a list of #, if a user is in this list, I want to exclude them from my current output:

Which contains users from the ooc-exceptions.csv, but if they are in that csv, I don't want to process them

I have already tried the following:

```
condition = lj_df['PrimaryUser'].isin(exclude_df['LastLogonUser'])
lj_df.drop(lj_df[condition].index, inplace = True)
```

but it doesn't display my end result

```
df = (lj_df.LastLogonUser)
```

```
Employee Number 
s128331
s150792 
s128535
s128726
s129103
P306823 
s129835 
s109424 
s125025 
P305503
```

```
dE = pd.read_csv("ooc-exceptions.csv")
```

```
prohibited users:
s110856
s129103
s128331
s131420
s128726
s128350
s128535
s110991
s141490
s145811
s150640
```

End Result should look like this:

```
s150792
P306823
s129835
s109424
s125025
P305503
```

If prohibited user, I don't want to display it.

Comment: You could use `isin` with negation operator: `df[~df['Employee_Number'].isin(prohibited['prohibited_users'])]`

Comment: what is df[~df?

Comment: How can i print the values instead of false/true?

Comment: please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sets` predicates and `isin` to filter out your dataframe:

```
allowed_users = set(df['Employee Number']).difference(dE['prohibited users'])

df['allowed users'] = df['Employee Number'].isin(allowed_users)
print(df)

# Output
  Employee Number  allowed users
0         s128331          False
1         s150792           True
2         s128535          False
3         s128726          False
4         s129103          False
5         P306823           True
6         s129835           True
7         s109424           True
8         s125025           True
9         P305503           True
```

To show allowed users:

```
>>> df[df['allowed users']]
  Employee Number  allowed users
1         s150792           True
5         P306823           True
6         s129835           True
7         s109424           True
8         s125025           True
9         P305503           True
```

Comment: i have other information in my datasets, not just the one coloumn, i keep getting keyerror: lastlogonuser' but that is in the dataset

Comment: What is the difference between `lj_df['PrimaryUser']` and `lj_df.LastLogonUser`?